# Operating with groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a question that is breaking my head.
Suppose that I have the next dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 4)),columns=['ONE', 'TWO', 'CARS', 'FOUR'])
df2['NAMES'] = ['Peter','Jon','Mary','Mary','Peter','Peter','BONIFACE','Michael','Lucy','Gilari']
df2['CARS'] = ['Mercedes','BMW','Ford','BMW','BMW','Dacia','Ford','Pontiac','Chevrolet','Tesla']
```

And I group it by cars, for example.

```
agrupe = df2.groupby(['CARS'])
```

The thing is that once I have grouped it I want to operate with it, for instance in the group made by BMW I want to assign the value of col 2 to col 4 from the elements that have a 2 on column ONE. Lets see If I learn to operate it:

```
g = agrupe.get_group('BMW')
```

And going from this

```
     ONE TWO CARS  FOUR  NAMES
1    1    0  BMW     1    Jon
3    2    1  BMW     1   Mary
4    0    1  BMW     0  Peter
```

to this:

```
    ONE  TWO CARS  FOUR  NAMES
1    1    0  BMW     1   Jon
3    2    1  BMW     1   Mary
4    0    1  BMW     1  Peter
```

Comment: Could you rephrase ` I want to assign the value of col 2 to col 4 from the elements that have a 2 on column ONE. ` ? Column `TWO` or column two = `CARS` ? Plus, the example given does not match what ur saying

Comment: Sorry, my native language is not english. I make groups by cars, and then I check the values of other column, lets say col ONE. THe values that have a 2 in col ONE will give their value of col TWO to col FOUR. I hope now it is more clear. Thank you

Comment: Not the problem. by col2 you mean column `TWO` or df.columns[2] ?

Comment: I have just edited my comment, I missclicked the enter. I hope now you understand the thing better @MMF,

Comment: @fra044 - In column `ONE` is no `2`, there is only `1,3,4`. Do you need work ony with group `BMW` after `agrupe.get_group('BMW')`? Or works with rows with `BMW` in `df2`?

Comment: @fra044 If jezrael understands your question then it's valid. If he doesn't then it's an invalid question :P

Comment: @jezrael No, mate. That is the index. My real df is much  more complex. I need to the check once made the groups the values of one column, and by one dominating value, pass their column value to another column. It is quite confusing, I know :(. Now dfs are more clear.

Comment: So think if in column `ONE` is `0` then change column `FOUR` by column `TWO`, right?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi - I much times was wrong ...

Comment: No, think if in column ONE there is a 2(for example), then pass the value of that element in col TWO  to col FOUR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function `f`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 4)),columns=['ONE', 'TWO', 'CARS', 'FOUR'])
df2['NAMES'] = ['Peter','Jon','Mary','Mary','Peter','Peter','BONIFACE','Michael','Lucy','Gilari']
df2['CARS'] = ['Mercedes','BMW','Ford','BMW','BMW','Dacia','Ford','Pontiac','Chevrolet','Tesla']
print (df2)
   ONE  TWO       CARS  FOUR     NAMES
0    0    0   Mercedes     2     Peter
1    2    0        BMW     1       Jon
2    2    2       Ford     2      Mary
3    1    0        BMW     0      Mary
4    0    2        BMW     1     Peter
5    1    2      Dacia     0     Peter
6    0    1       Ford     1  BONIFACE
7    0    0    Pontiac     1   Michael
8    1    2  Chevrolet     2      Lucy
9    1    1      Tesla     2    Gilari
```

```
def f(x):
    if (x.name == 'BMW'):
        x.loc[x.ONE == 2, 'FOUR'] = x.TWO
    return x

agrupe = df2.groupby('CARS').apply(f)
print (agrupe)
   ONE  TWO       CARS  FOUR     NAMES
0    0    0   Mercedes     2     Peter
1    2    0        BMW     0       Jon
2    2    2       Ford     2      Mary
3    1    0        BMW     0      Mary
4    0    2        BMW     1     Peter
5    1    2      Dacia     0     Peter
6    0    1       Ford     1  BONIFACE
7    0    0    Pontiac     1   Michael
8    1    2  Chevrolet     2      Lucy
9    1    1      Tesla     2    Gilari
```

---

Better solution is first select all rows where column `CARS` is `BMW` and column `ONE` is `2` and then change `FOUR` by column `TWO`:

```
df2.loc[(df2.CARS == 'BMW') & (df2.ONE == 2), 'FOUR'] = df2.TWO
print (df2)
   ONE  TWO       CARS  FOUR     NAMES
0    0    0   Mercedes     2     Peter
1    2    0        BMW     0       Jon
2    2    2       Ford     2      Mary
3    1    0        BMW     0      Mary
4    0    2        BMW     1     Peter
5    1    2      Dacia     0     Peter
6    0    1       Ford     1  BONIFACE
7    0    0    Pontiac     1   Michael
8    1    2  Chevrolet     2      Lucy
9    1    1      Tesla     2    Gilari
```

Or if need change if `2` in column `ONE` so change column `FOUR` by column `TWO`:

```
np.random.seed(13)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 4)),columns=['ONE', 'TWO', 'CARS', 'FOUR'])
df2['NAMES'] = ['Peter','Jon','Mary','Mary','Peter','Peter','BONIFACE','Michael','Lucy','Gilari']
df2['CARS'] = ['Mercedes','BMW','Ford','BMW','BMW','Dacia','Ford','Pontiac','Chevrolet','Tesla']
print (df2)
   ONE  TWO       CARS  FOUR     NAMES
0    2    0   Mercedes     0     Peter
1    2    2        BMW     1       Jon
2    0    2       Ford     0      Mary
3    2    2        BMW     2      Mary
4    1    1        BMW     1     Peter
5    0    2      Dacia     1     Peter
6    2    1       Ford     2  BONIFACE
7    0    0    Pontiac     0   Michael
8    2    2  Chevrolet     0      Lucy
9    1    1      Tesla     2    Gilari


df2.loc[df2.ONE == 2, 'FOUR'] = df2.TWO
print (df2)
   ONE  TWO       CARS  FOUR     NAMES
0    2    0   Mercedes     0     Peter
1    2    2        BMW     2       Jon
2    0    2       Ford     0      Mary
3    2    2        BMW     2      Mary
4    1    1        BMW     1     Peter
5    0    2      Dacia     1     Peter
6    2    1       Ford     1  BONIFACE
7    0    0    Pontiac     0   Michael
8    2    2  Chevrolet     2      Lucy
9    1    1      Tesla     2    Gilari
```

Comment: That looks pretty nice. Let me check. Thanks

Comment: It is not right. I grouped by cars and then worked with BMW just for an example. The thing is that once I have grouped i dont know the names of each group so   if (x.name == 'BMW'): is wrong, once deleted that part the function doesnt work well at all.    I have used this part                                                                                                              def f(x):
    x.loc[x.ONE == 2, 'FOUR'] = x.TWO
    return x

Comment: Now how does it work? `def f(x): x.loc[x.ONE == 2, 'FOUR'] = x.TWO return x` is same and faster as `df2.loc[df2.ONE == 2, 'FOUR'] = df2.TWO`

Comment: The thing is that in last change elements are not grouped, so that you change the value of col FOUR in the whole group.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. If need specify group by value (`BMW`) and value `2` in column `ONE` is possible use `df2.loc[(df2.CARS == 'BMW') & (df2.ONE == 2), 'FOUR'] = df2.TWO`. If not, why? Can you explain more?

Comment: The specification by group of BMW was just an example. I make groups by a column name and then i have to use those group as little dataframes, that is the general idea.  Thanks for your efforts

Comment: ok, so if my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it. Thanks.